# Matplotlib: fill_between drawing rounded edges in SVG when color is set

Tags: python, matplotlib, svg

I've encountered a strange issue when using matplotlibs [fill_between](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.fill_between.html) with data that has a tight gap. For example, when I simply want to plot the following data and save it as SVG, it works:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.fill_between([0,1e4-1000,1e4,1e4+1000,1e6], [1000,1000,1,1000,1000])
plt.savefig("test.svg")
```

[image]

But when I set the color to any value, the gap disappears:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.fill_between([0,1e4-1000,1e4,1e4+1000,1e6], [1000,1000,1,1000,1000], color='tab:red')
plt.savefig("test_colored.svg")
```

[image]

After zooming in I noticed the edge line is drawn with rounded borders:
[image]

How can I change the plot color without this gap disappearing?
I've tried to set different kwargs like `capstyle`, `joinstyle`, `antialiased`, `rasterized`,... to all possible values without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the `color` of the patch. This would include the edgecolor and the facecolor. However, it seems you only want to have the face colored. Hence use `facecolor='tab:red'`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.fill_between([0,1e4-1000,1e4,1e4+1000,1e6], [1000,1000,1,1000,1000], facecolor='tab:red')
plt.savefig("test_colored.svg")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Do I understand it correctly that by default the edge is not drawn, but when I set its color it is drawn, causing an overlapping effect?

Comment: Yes, you could choose `edgecolor="k"` to see this effect.